# How can I fire animations without queueing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Each of these 3 divs travels 500px over 6000ms. After 4000ms, I want:

1. the red div to fade out over its last 2000ms
2. the green dive to fade in over 2000ms
3. the green div to start its journey of 500px

all simultaneously.

Then, after 8000ms, when the green div is 4000ms into its journey, I want:

1. the green div to fade out over its last 2000ms
2. the yellow dive to fade in over 2000ms
3. the yellow div to start its journey of 500px

all simultaneously.

Then, at 12000ms, when the yellow div is 4000ms into its journey, I want it to fade out over its last 2000ms of its journey.

It's about having total control with overlapping animations. I tried queue() and dequeue(), queue: false, setTimeout... I can't make heads or tails of it. How do I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        div {
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            }
        #div1 {background:red;top:0;}
        #div2 {background:green;top:55px;}
        #div3 {background:yellow;top:110px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#div1").animate({left: "500px"}, 6000);
            $("#div2").delay(4000).animate({left: "500px"}, 6000);
            $("#div3").delay(8000).animate({left: "500px"}, 6000);
        });
        </script>
        <div id="div1"></div>
        <div id="div2"></div>
        <div id="div3"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is requirement for each `div` to fade out over the last 2000ms of the animation ?

Comment: Yes. a div fades out while another one fades in. It could be 1500ms or 1000ms, this is just simple example to explain what I'm struggling with. It's the problem of overlapping animations I want to solve to create a crossfading slideshow with Ken Burns effect.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to implement?

```js
idArray = ['div1', 'div2', 'div3', 'div4'];
div = {};
//Create a flag for every item in list.
$(idArray).each(function(i, val) {
  div['Action' + i] = false;
});
duration = 6000; //duration of each animation
overlap = 4000; //the time when overlap happens
fadeAt = 2000; //speed at which element appear/disappear
iLikeToMoveIt(0); //initialize animation

function iLikeToMoveIt(i) {
  $now = $("#" + idArray[i]); //animation element
  $next = $("#" + idArray[++i]); //next element
  $now.fadeIn(fadeAt).animate({
    left: "500px"
  }, {
    duration: 6000,
    queue: false,
    progress: function(animation, progress, remainingMs) {
      //check if flag is not set
      if (!div['Action' + i] && remainingMs < fadeAt) {
        //set the flag
        div['Action' + i] = true;
        $(this).fadeOut(fadeAt);
        if ($next.length) {
          //call function for next div
          iLikeToMoveIt(i);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
#div1 {
  background: red;
  top: 0;
}
#div2 {
  background: green;
  top: 55px;
}
#div3 {
  background: yellow;
  top: 110px;
}
#div4 {
  background: blue;
  top: 165px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2" class="hide"></div>
<div id="div3" class="hide"></div>
<div id="div4" class="hide"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. The green div and the red div should be "display none" and then fade in as the previous div fades out. That's the only thing your code is not doing, but it's because I did not set the css for the green and yellow div to "display none" in order to show my example. Thank you Rejith R Krishnan, you answered my question yesterday with a simpler example, but I ran into trouble when I tried to extend that example to the one I posted here today.

Comment: @Kobbe ok. I'll try to generalize it.

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you Rejith R Krishnan, much appreciated.

Comment: @Kobbe I made a more generalized function for it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you again Rejith R Krishnan. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `css` `transition` and `start` , `step` options of `.animate()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    div {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      transition: opacity 2.5s ease;
    }
    #div1 {
      background: red;
      top: 0;
    }
    #div2 {
      background: green;
      top: 55px;
      opacity:0;
    }
    #div3 {
      background: yellow;
      top: 110px;
      opacity:0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      
      function step(now, fx) {
        var n = Math.round(now)
        if (n === 250 || n === 251) {         
          $(this).css("opacity", 0)
        }
      }
      
      function start() {
        $(this).css("opacity", 1)
      }
      
      $("#div1").animate({
        left: "500px"
      }, {
        duration: 6000,
        step:step
      });
      $("#div2").delay(4000).animate({
        left: "500px"
      }, {
        duration: 6000,
        start:start,
        step:step
      });
      $("#div3").delay(8000).animate({
        left: "500px"
      }, {
        duration: 6000,
        start:start,
        step:step
      });
    });
  </script>
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your solution works too. As I explained to Rejith R Krishnan, the goal is the have the green and yellow div set to "display:none; in css and have them fade in while the previous div is fading out.

Comment: @Kobbe _"the goal is the have the green and yellow div set to "display:none; in css and have them fade in while the previous div is fading out"_ You can use same approach , and include `start` function at options to toggle `opacity` of element at beginning of `.animate()` , see updated post

Comment: Thank you so much, I would not have been able to find this on my own. I don't only have a solution to the problem, but I will learn a lot from both your answer and that of Rejith R Krishnan when I pick it apart.